# Will permanent inverted current damage my relay module or even my electronic system?

Tags: voltage, relay, hacking

So I have an expensive piece of electronic equipment which emits ionizing radiation and I need it to set off a warning lightbulb on the wall.

The support company is asking me an overpriced solution so I decided to investigate my own solution which I figure out can be done for less than 5 bucks:

Radiation is only emitted when the button on the remote control is pressed. This remote control is connected to the main device via a 3 pair cable (RJ12 6p6c) I've measured every voltage differential between the pairs on all states and found a useful pair:
Unpressed button normal state: 24 V
Unpressed button armed state: 24 V
Pressed button unarmed state (not emitting radiation): -1 V
Pressed button armed state (emits the radiation): -22 V

My first idea was just to connect a bulb to this wires but that didn't work 1) the led 24v bulb lights up  in either polarity; 2) it triggers a buzzer and light on the remote command continuously

Since I have some 5V relay modules laying around I've did some testing and noted that the module only triggers if I have the right polarity (+ on VCC and IN and - on Ground) and stays off/untriggred if I invert the current (- on VCC and IN and + on Ground). So my second idea was to buy this:
[image: 24V relay module]

and can connect the above pair inverted so it will only let a 250V bulb light up when the button is pressed while in armed state.

My questions are:

1. Is it safe to leave the relay module with inverted voltage for a long time? Can it burn or sth?
2. Is that setup safe for the equipment? Can the VCC/GND used pairs short or receive voltage from the relay module?

Edit (schematic as requested):
[image: circuit schematic]

a/b will be:

- Unpressed button normal state: -24 V
- Unpressed button armed state: -24 V
- Pressed button unarmed state (not emitting radiation): 1 V
- Pressed button armed state (emits the radiation): 22 V

Comment: Do you know if those cables you want to connect that relay to are meant to drive a low impedance loqd like the relay. I would worry more about the "expensive piece of electronic" than the relay

Comment: Dealing with ionizing radiation on the cheap using AliBaba modules, and asking very basic questions, sounds like something that won't end well. My guess is that once you figure out the cost of insurance and potential litigation, the support company's prices will start looking very reasonable.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the manual/datasheet for the radiation emitter?  I wouldn't be surprised if it had some sort of auxiliary output made for this.  Connecting to an e.g. isolated open-collector or switched 24V warning signal is much safer than hacking a hobby-grade pcb into the control signal.

Comment: schematic added @jsotola

Comment: @vir I did check. It requires an optional module. The current auxiliary output in use is 220V and lights the bulb for the entire operation of the machine instead of just when "firing".

Comment: The OP has a source of ionizing radiation but is too cheap to buy the auxiliary equipment - this seems to poor practice - considering that the light is likely to be a regulatory or safety requirement. When I've seen this done, there is an additional interlock to inhibit the radiation if the indicating light bulb has burnt out. I think it should indicate the state of the radiation source, not the state of the input switch. And the circuit and its housing and trunking is built like a tank.

Comment: As others have said this sounds like a bad idea.  There may even be safety regulations (depending on details and location) that specify the way this gets done.  For example it's possible that no single point failure should cause a loss of the safety function (warning light).  You may even have to prove that with an FMEA and tests.  Also interfacing to some lines with unknown drive characteristics could cause issues as well.

Comment: @jsotola one) simple multimeter; two) my mistake while drawing the schematic, corrected!

Comment: @JohnD and @D Duck I really agree that there should be a mechanism where if the warning light isn't working the device itself should fault and not work. I'm really dumbfounded as that is not default design. But it isn't and the support company solution is to add bigger remote control to the wall (with a big button that illuminates when the other one is pressed... so no FMEA anyway just another button to pass as a warning light for a ridiculous price...)

Comment: Honestly, I would take the ego hit and outsource since it sounds like your company is willing to pay for it.  Is it an expensive design for a "simple" solution?  Perhaps.  But compared to a potential lawsuit from someone who was inadvertently dosed it's a bargain at twice the price (obviously not to mention the moral "cost", etc etc).  No personal reflection on you but it does sound like you're a bit out of your comfort zone on this and when life is literally on the line there's no shame at all in getting some help here and there.

Comment: @jsotola the communication between the device and the remote control is made via a 6pin6cable connection I tested every negative/positive DMM combination between those 6 wires until I found something useful (i.e. some voltage diference that I could try using as a trigger)

Comment: _"the module only triggers if I have the right polarity (+ on VCC **and IN** and - on Ground)"_ - not according to your schematic it doesn't. Please show us the correct schematic.